# M2 - Preselecting a customizable option in a simple product by URL

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, products

Is it possible to select a customizable option (size) of a simple product by URL? Or is that only working for configurable products? I basically need one URL per size/option for each product.
How can I achieve that with Magento 2.3?

Below is the Markup for the Dropdown,how can I select an option there by URL parameters? 
[image: Dropdown Values]

Comment: simple products are always fully configured. and not fully configured products don't exist. you might want to solve this with a request parameter. use javascript to do this

Comment: What does a request parameter look like for the example above? How can I select one of the options by URL?

Comment: you have to build it your own. this is not out of the box functionality

Comment: I wonder why, because with configurable products it is possible with the # Url Fragments. Any idea on how to start implementing this for simple products?

Answer (score 0):

To preselect a simple product in a configurable product, the address of a simple product should look like this for example:

> **`/mona-pullover-hoodlie.html#143=167&93=53`**

where `/mona-pullover-hoodlie.html` - configurable product URL, `143`, `93` - attributes IDs, `167`, `53` - option IDs.

In order to change the URL of simple products, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for **`Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getProductUrl()`**, where to generate the URL as in the example above.

I made `VCT Simple Product URL` module on Magento Marketplace that solves this problem.